# How to disable start date to end date in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

> I want to make the year 2020-06-10 previous date disable.

> When I again set the date for another entry I want to show the years 2020-06-11 to infinity.

> I want to disable all previous Activation date when select Expiration Date.

> I use NgZorro Library.

> If anyone uses my code to solve that problem that would be a great pleasure for me.

[image]

[image]

> LateFee Component

```
export class LateFeeCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.lateFeeForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [null],
      percentage: ['', Validators.required],
      activationDate: ['', Validators.required],
      expirationDate: ['', Validators.required],

    });
    this.onStartLateFeeEdit$ =
      this.conservancyChargeService.onStartLateFeeEditing.subscribe(
        (id: number) => {
          this.editedItemId = id;
          this.isEditMode = this.editedItemId !== null;
          this.editedItem = this.conservancyChargeService.getLateFeeById(id);
          this.lateFeeForm.patchValue(this.editedItem);
        }
      );
  }
  submitForm(): void {
    for (const key of Object.keys(this.lateFeeForm.controls)) {
      this.lateFeeForm.controls[key].markAsDirty();
      this.lateFeeForm.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
    this.lateFee = this.lateFeeForm.value;
    if (this.onEditingLateFeeId != null) {
      this.conservancyChargeStorageService.updateLateFee(this.lateFee)
        .subscribe({ next: (response) => this.notification.success('Success!', 'LateFee update successfully'),
          error: (error) => this.notification.error('Failed', error),
        });
    }

    else {
      this.conservancyChargeStorageService.createLateFee(this.lateFee)
        .subscribe({ next: (response) => this.notification.success('Success!', 'LateFee create successfully'),
          error: (error) => this.notification.error('Failed', 'Please! provide valid information'),
        });
    }

    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(): void {
    this.lateFeeForm.reset();
    this.isEditMode = false;
    for (const key of Object.keys(this.lateFeeForm.controls)) {
      this.lateFeeForm.controls[key].markAsPristine();
      this.lateFeeForm.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  }
}
```

> Latefee.component.html

```
<nz-card nzTitle="Create Late Fee" [nzExtra]="extraTemplate">
  <form nz-form [formGroup]="lateFeeForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">

    <div nz-row [nzGutter]="{ xs: 8, sm: 16, md: 24, lg: 32 }">
      <div nz-col class="gutter-row" [nzSpan]="6">

        <nz-form-item>
          <nz-form-label [nzSpan]="24" nzRequired> Percentage</nz-form-label>
          <nz-form-control [nzSpan]="20" nzHasFeedback nzValidatingTip="Validating..." [nzErrorTip]="lateFeeErrorTpl">
            <input nz-input formControlName="percentage" placeholder="percentage" />
            <ng-template #lateFeeErrorTpl let-control>
              <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">
                Please input  percentage!
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('duplicated')">
                The percentage is redundant!
              </ng-container>
            </ng-template>
          </nz-form-control>
        </nz-form-item>

      </div>
      <div nz-col class="gutter-row" [nzSpan]="6">
        <nz-form-item>
          <nz-form-label [nzSpan]="24" nzRequired> Active Date</nz-form-label>
          <nz-form-control [nzSpan]="20" nzHasFeedback [nzErrorTip]="lateFeeErrorTpl">
            <nz-date-picker style="width: 100%;" formControlName="activationDate" placeholder="Activation Date" ></nz-date-picker>
            <ng-template #lateFeeErrorTpl let-control>
              <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">
                Please input valid date!
              </ng-container>
            </ng-template>
          </nz-form-control>
        </nz-form-item>
      </div>

      <div nz-col class="gutter-row" [nzSpan]="6">
        <nz-form-item>
          <nz-form-label [nzSpan]="24" nzRequired> Expiry Date</nz-form-label>
          <nz-form-control [nzSpan]="20" nzHasFeedback [nzErrorTip]="lateFeeErrorTpl">
            <nz-date-picker style="width: 100%;" formControlName="expirationDate" placeholder="Expiration Date" ></nz-date-picker>
            <ng-template #lateFeeErrorTpl let-control>
              <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">
                Please input valid date!
              </ng-container>
            </ng-template>
          </nz-form-control>
        </nz-form-item>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div nz-row [nzGutter]="{ xs: 8, sm: 16, md: 24, lg: 32 }">
      <div nz-col class="gutter-row" [nzSpan]="6" style="margin-top: 36px;">
        <div nz-row>
          <div nz-col [nzSpan]="24" class="search-area">
            <button nz-button type="submit" nzType="primary" [disabled]="!lateFeeForm.valid"><i
              nz-icon nzType="save" nzTheme="fill"></i>{{isEditMode?'Update':'Submit'}}</button>
              <button nz-button nzType="primary" nzDanger (click)="resetForm()" style="margin-left: 11px;">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</nz-card>
```

Comment: I would need more information to give a more accurate answer. You might want to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you can make a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) we can more easily take a look at your code.

Comment: I write my code. If you solve my problem that is so much helpful.

Comment: I am not familiar with nz-datepicker, sorry. But it looks like you need to use the [nzDisabledDate] property.

Comment: I know [nzDisabledDate] property. But that property doesn't serve my problem in a proper way.

Comment: And if you think my question now is good then, please vote my question.

Comment: Hi, if my answer  resolve your problem please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function like below and add your logic for disabled dates.

```
public disabledDate = (current: Date): boolean => current < new Date(); // put your logic here
```

and change your html code like below

```
    <nz-date-picker [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate" style="width: 100%;" formControlName="expirationDate" placeholder="Expiration Date"  ></nz-date-picker>
```

Also I had same issue too then I fixed it like above.

You can check this ["Disabled Date & Time
"](https://ng.ant.design/components/date-picker/en#components-date-picker-demo-presetted-ranges)  section for extra information

Here and example that I used **nzDisabledDate** property for disable previous days

[image]